# d3 Not understanding how to change attr

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am a complete beginner to d3. I am looking at this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8

Here he is changing x, y axis information. In the same example, how would one change the actual height of the chart (say increase it by 100) when the update button is clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One would simply increase the `range` of the `y` scale by 100.

```
// Set the ranges:
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Update the ranges (on click or whatever):
y.range([height + 100, 0]);
```

Then, the chart would update basing on this new `y` scale.

Comment: Thanks, are there ways to alter margin.height on button click as well?

Comment: Sure, `margin.height += 100;` and then update the `<svg>` element by `d3.select('svg').attr('height', height + margin.height);`

Comment: How does one change a 'g' element within svg? Say changing the variable variable in this line:  svg = svg.append("g").attr("Variable", variable);

Comment: The `.attr` is a getter/setter. If you have a `<div></div>` on your page, then `d3.select('div').attr('hi', 'there')` will result in `<div hi="there"></div>`. And `d3.select('div').attr('hi');` will return a string `"there"`.